# Convert an iteration to recursion

Tags: scala, recursion

I have an iteration logic that returns a query like this :

```
val baseQuery = s"select agg_id from quality.QUALITY_AGGREGATOR where job_id = 123 and level ="
val reprocessDate ="2018-10-24"
for( i <- 0 to level){
  var currLevelSubQuery=""
  if (i==0 ){
   currLevelSubQuery= baseQuery + s"$i and agg_value >= '${reprocessDate}'"
  }
  else{
   currLevelSubQuery= baseQuery + s"$i and  parent_agg_id  in ( $prevLevelSubQuery )"
  }
  prevLevelSubQuery= currLevelSubQuery
  finalQuery = finalQuery + currLevelSubQuery + (if (i<level) " union " else "")
}
```

It returns a query of this nature for level = 2.

```
SELECT agg_id 
FROM   quality.quality_aggregator 
WHERE  job_id = 123 
       AND level = 0 
       AND agg_value >= '2018-10-24' 
UNION 
SELECT agg_id 
FROM   quality.quality_aggregator 
WHERE  job_id = 123 
       AND level = 1 
       AND parent_agg_id IN (SELECT agg_id 
                             FROM   quality.quality_aggregator 
                             WHERE  job_id = 123 
                                    AND level = 0 
                                    AND agg_value >= '2018-10-24') 
UNION 
SELECT agg_id 
FROM   quality.quality_aggregator 
WHERE  job_id = 123 
       AND level = 2 
       AND parent_agg_id IN (SELECT agg_id 
                             FROM   quality.quality_aggregator 
                             WHERE  job_id = 123 
                                    AND level = 1 
                                    AND parent_agg_id IN 
                                        (SELECT agg_id 
                                         FROM   quality.quality_aggregator 
                                         WHERE  job_id = 123 
                                                AND level = 0 
                                                AND agg_value >= 
                                                    '2018-10-24'))
```

I am trying to convert it into a recursive logic like this

```
    val baseQuery = s"select agg_id from quality.QUALITY_AGGREGATOR where job_id = 123 and level ="
    val finalQuery = getAggIdSQLGenerator(2,"2018-10-24")
    def getAggIdSQLGenerator(level : Int,   reprocessDate:String):String={
       if (level == 0)
          (  baseQuery + s"$level and agg_value >= '${reprocessDate}'") 
        else  
        {
         val subQuery=getAggIdSQLGenerator(level-1 ,reprocessDate)
         baseQuery + s"$level and  parent_agg_id  in (" +subQuery +")   union "+ subQuery
        }
    }
```

But this is not yielding correct results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't recursive but I think it's a smaller, cleaner, implementation of what you're after.

```
val baseQuery = ".... level="
val levelRE = "level=(\\d+)".r.unanchored

val reprocessDate ="2018-10-24"
val av = s" and agg_value >= '${reprocessDate}'"
val pai = " and parent_agg_id in "

val itrs = 3
val query = List.iterate(s"${baseQuery}0$av", itrs) { prevStr =>
  val level = prevStr match {
    case levelRE(n) => n.toInt + 1
    case _ => 0
  }
  s"$baseQuery$level$pai($prevStr)"
}.mkString(" union ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have added union on every query and you have concatenated subquery 2 times.

This gives your expected output.

```
val baseQuery = s"select agg_id from quality.QUALITY_AGGREGATOR where job_id = 123 and level ="

val finalQuery = getAggIdSQLGenerator(2, "2018-10-24")

def getAggIdSQLGenerator(level: Int, reprocessDate: String): String = {
  if (level == 0) {
    baseQuery + s" $level and agg_value >= '${reprocessDate}'"
  } else {
    val subQuery = getAggIdSQLGenerator(level - 1, reprocessDate)
    baseQuery + s" $level and  parent_agg_id  in (" + subQuery + ")"
  }
}

println("UNION " + finalQuery)
```

Comment: this returns only the subquery for level 2 not other levels . My expected output needs this structure level0 union level1 ( with level0 as subquery) union level 2 (with level 1 & level 0 as subquery)

Comment: You can't create that with this recursive function at once. You can call it 3 times with 3 different levels to get the 3 different sections. I don't see any other possible way than having a for() loop somewhere.